# Update tableView by NSMutableArray [UIRefreshControl]

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uirefreshcontrol

I have tableview read from NSMutableArray, and using UIRefreshControl what I need is updating NSMutableArray without crashing or deleteing contents before updating.

Let's say from first time NSMutableArray has 4 rows, during refreshing the NSMutableArray has 5 rows so there is 1 row added.

I used this but it crashed.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.objects removeAllObjects];
...
..
Adding new objects in self.objects
...
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Any hint?

Comment: Remove the calls to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`

Comment: @dan Works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: beginUpdates/endUpdates using for deleteRows ..etc. Got it.